# How to convert sentences to math notation

Tags: logic

The probability that a specific relationship exists between two objects $(x,y)$ in a graph using probability model.
How to write it down using a math notation.
for example:

$f(z)= p$ if there is a relation between $x$ and $y$ 
$f(z)=0$  if no relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to define a piecewise function. You can write this in the following way:

$f(z)=\begin{cases} p & \text{ if } R(x,y),\\ 0 &\text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}$

Here, $R$ is whatever relation you have on $x$ and $y$. As your function also depends on $x$ and $y$, you can write $f_{x,y}(z)$ or $f(z, x,y)$ instead of $f(z)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, James Leslie. Please check 
The problem is mathematically defined for the probabilistic graph GS. Let X={x_1,x_2,x_3,…..,x_n} be the set of all objects and R={r_1,r_2,r_3} be the set of all relation types in a GS. Each possible relationship are modeled as fi,j,k= (xi , rk,xj ) over this set of objects as a binary random variable f_(ci,cj) (K). 
f_(xi,xj) (y)={█(p   if  R(x_i,x_j)@  0     Otherwise)┤
Where P to estimate the likelihood that a R edge exists between Xi and Xj.
I define P as a probability function
p^k  =d_k/N